# Best way to sort list with index array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I would like to sort a list of strings with an array of integers as the new indexes:

```
Integer[] newIndexes = {0,2,1};
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add("Apple");
fruits.add("Pear");
fruits.add("Banana");
fruits.sort....
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Just use a `TreeMap<Integer, String>`, put index and string and then get the values sorted by index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SortedMap` to map the integers to the string values. This way it will sort the string values according to the natural ordering of the keys:

```
SortedMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
for (int i = 0; i < newIndexes.length; i++) {
    map.put(newIndexes[i], fruits.get(i));
}

Collection<String> sortedFruits = map.values();
```

If you intend to sort the strings alphabetically, then you can just use `Collections#sort()`.

Answer (score 3):

Using Java 8, you can do it using a stream of the indexes and the `map()` method:

```
List<String> sortedFruits = Stream.of(newIndexes).map(fruits::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

gives the list

```
[Apple, Banana, Pear]
```

Comment: sadly enough i have to use Java 7, still +1